Application autoscaling not scaling down the provisioned concurrency
So I have a stack with lambda. It has application auto scaling enabled for that lambda alias and it autoscales when the provisioned concurrency utilization exceeds the target value. But it's not scaling down when the utilization is below the target.
alias = aws_lambda.Alias(
    scope=scope,
    id=f"{function_name}FunctionAlias",
    alias_name=get_alias_name(function_name),
    version=current_version,
    provisioned_concurrent_executions=provisioned_concurrent_executions,
)
alias.apply_removal_policy(removal_policy)

if autoscaling:

    scaling_target = aws_applicationautoscaling.ScalableTarget(
        scope=scope,
        id=f"{function_name}ScalableTarget",
        service_namespace=aws_applicationautoscaling.ServiceNamespace.LAMBDA,
        min_capacity=scaling_target_min_capacity,
        max_capacity=scaling_target_max_capacity,
        resource_id=f"function:{function_name}:{get_alias_name(function_name)}",
        scalable_dimension="lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency",
    )
    scaling_target.node.add_dependency(alias)

    metric = aws_cloudwatch.Metric(
        metric_name="ProvisionedConcurrencyUtilization",
        namespace="AWS/Lambda",
        statistic="Maximum",
        dimensions_map={
            "FunctionName": function_name,
            "Resource": f"{function_name}:{get_alias_name(function_name)}",
        },
        period=Duration.minutes(1),
        unit=aws_cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
    )
    scaling_target.scale_to_track_metric(
        "PCU",
        target_value=0.5,
        custom_metric=metric,
    )

I am not sure, which unit is used by the ProvisionedConcurrencyUtilization metrics but for now we have been using the count.
I sent numerous events to trigger the lambda using provisioned concurrency. And it autoscales once it crosses the target but once I stop sending the request it doesn't autoscale to minimum configured value. This blog mentioned that  they were also facing similar issue while testing.
